# Unable to save new VisualForce pages in developer console

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites

I have developer account created on Salesforce.com, I was able to create APEX classes and Visualforce pages using the 'developer console'.

All of a sudden now my visualforce pages are not getting saved. 
The star sign adjacent to the filename tab always remains same even after repeatedly pressing 'ctrl+s'(as seen below)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it gives no indication of any problems (no icon on the problems tab) and it also gives no indication that it's still trying to save - I'd say copy the VF page and close the dev console. I'm not exactly sure what the issue may be, but the quickest and best option is to just close and open it again.

Refresh your salesforce home page to make sure you're still logged in. Re-open dev console again, paste your VF code, and try saving again. I also find that copying and pasting the url of the dev console into its own browser tab to work better than keeping it in its own window when it pops up.

Comment: Just closing and opening is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save Apex of VF pages directly in a Production environment. You need to save them in a sandbox, then deploy. From the screen cap, I see you're accessing the instance ap15 which is a production instance (Asia Pacific).

Note: I've heard others suggest you can edit VF in prod, but that is not my experience.

Comment: I created a developer account and tried to save a APEX class file, but does'nt save. View the steps performed in this video recording https://bit.ly/2MF0c5Y

Comment: The answer is late, but ... on line 4, in your video, you have String() instead of String[]. This prevented you from saving (as the message indicates).